# Case Insensitive Python string split() method

Tags: python, string

I have 2 strings

```
a = "abc feat. def"
b = "abc Feat. def"
```

I want to retrieve the string before the word `feat.` or `Feat.`

This is what I'm doing,

```
a.split("feat.", 1)[0].rstrip()
```

This returns `abc`. But how can I perform a case insensitive search using split delimiter?

This is what I've tried so far

```
b.split("feat." or "Feat.", 1)[0].rstrip()
```

Output - `abc Feat. def`

`b.split("feat." and "Feat.", 1)[0].rstrip()`

Output - `abc`

`a.split("feat." and "Feat.", 1)[0].rstrip()`

Output - `abc feat. def`.

`a.split("feat." or "Feat.", 1)[0].rstrip()`

Output - `abc`

Why is this difference with `and` and `or` in both the cases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`a[0:a.lower().find("feat.")].rstrip()` would do.

`and`ing

`"string1" and "string2" and ... and "stringN"`

returns the the last string.

`or`ing

`"string1" or "string2" or ... or "stringN"`

would return the first string.

[Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 17):

Use a regex instead:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\s*feat\.\s*", flags=re.I)
>>> regex.split("abc feat. def")
['abc', 'def']
>>> regex.split("abc Feat. def")
['abc', 'def']
```

or, if you don't want to allow `FEAT.` or `fEAT.` (which this regex would):

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r"\s*[Ff]eat\.\s*")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use regex:

```
re.split('\s*[Ff]eat\.', a)
```

`and` and `or` do some boolean judgement.

```
"feat." or "Feat." -> "feat." if "feat." else "Feat." -> "feat."

"feat." and "Feat." -> "Feat." if "feat." else "feat." -> "Feat."
```